# Block or Disable USB tethering using Windows AD GroupPolicy

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

For Windows based PCs connected with Windows AD with Group policy, we want to block USB phone tethering options. And we have tried following things which seems to be working for some people but not us.

We have applied computer policy to block device installation

System/Device Installation/Device Installation Restrictions > Prevent installation of devices that match any of these device IDs

Device ID `USB\class_e0`

This was described [on Microsoft Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/68c09a6a-07ec-47da-b4e1-d5dd325cc57f/prevent-mtp-amp-usb-tethering?forum=w7itprosecurity). I have also reviewed the process described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/manage-device-installation-with-group-policy).

I am just not sure whether device ID `USB\class_e0` is the correct one or not?

Also, I check hardware IDs of few phones and all of them have distinct IDs like

#### Device 1

- `USB\VID_22D9&PID_276A&REV_0404&MI_00`
- `USB\VID_22D9&PID_276A&MI_00`

#### Device 2

- `USB\VID_2717&PID_FF80&REV_0404&MI_00`
- `USB\VID_2717&PID_FF80&MI_00`

#### Device 3

- `USB\VID_04E8&PID_6863&REV_0400&MI_00`
- `USB\VID_04E8&PID_6863&MI_00`

Now, when I add the complete device ID, the policy works as expected, i.e. the device is not installed and thus usb tethering now blocked for that particular device. Please check my current policy screenshot:

[image: Policy settings screenshot]

What is wrong, and how to resolve this to block all devices without adding each device IDs?

Comment: Obviously this setting will not work if an endpoint does not have an expected setting value, and is not a valid approach. I'm curious though, have you enabled the policy setting that disables other network adapters when connected to a domain network? I know that works with wireless, not sure what adapter type these are.

Comment: https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.WindowsConnectionManager::WCM_BlockNonDomain

Comment: how can we do this https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.WindowsConnectionManager::WCM_BlockNonDomain using Group Policy?

Comment: To check if the setting is enabled, you need to use regedit and check for the registry value `HKLM\ Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WcmSvc\GroupPolicy!fBlockNonDomain`

Comment: Can this setting be enabled using group policy? If yes, how?

Comment: It IS a group policy setting.

Comment: Didn't noticed that!